¿Como puedo poner una etiqueta html de video en segundo plano en movil?
Tengo la siguiente etiqueta <video class="view-user"></video> quiero ponerle la funcionalidad de que en un teléfono se pueda visualizar el video mientras estoy en otras aplicaciones.

Me podría ayudar si se trata de una libreria, configuración o al menos saber como se llama la funcionalidad?

En android la conozco como "picture-in-picture", pero es una configuración de la app como tal, mas no del video en sí.
